# Number of $1's$ in a string in terms of successive pairs

Tags: combinatorics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> **Problem.** Let $X_n=0$ or $1$ and set $Y_n=(X_n,X_{n+1})$. Set also $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{\{X_k=1\}}$ be the number of times $X_k's$ become $1$, from $X_1$ till $X_n$ ($\mathbb{I}_{A}$ is the indicator of set $A$). Can this sum be described in terms of the $Y_n'$s?

I have started working with some easy strings of $0$'s and $1$'s but i can't seem to be making a pattern out of it!

Thanks a lot in  advance!

Comment: Your problem, as stated, seems unclear.

Comment: I am having a string of length, say n, of $0'$s and $1'$s (call them $X_n's$) and I would like, if possible, to express the (unknown) number of $1$'s in terms of the successive pairs in my string. For example, if we have 5 $1's$ in a string of length $10$, i.e. $5$ X_i's are $1$ (for example $(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0)$), can this number, $5$, be described in terms of the values of the successive pairs $Y_1=(X_1,X_2),\ldots,Y_9$'s? (maybe an inclusion - exclusion principle).

Comment: If we know the sequence of successive pairs, then we know the original sequence. But I don't think  that can be what you are asking.

Comment: Please, let me state it this way: I am working a problem on markov chains, where i have a non-markov chain $\{X_n\}$ of $0$'s and $1$'s.  I can work though with sequence $Y_n=(X_n,X_{n+1})$ (which is markov). I have reached the point that I should use the ergodic theorem, to find the mean value of the number of times $X_n's$ become $1$ (that in $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{\{X_n=1\}}$, but since $\{X_n\}$ is not markov, I should (if I can of course!) write this sum in terms of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{\{Y_n=??\}}$ (plus, minus something). I think I am on the right path...

Comment: There are $4$ possible values of $Y_n$. Define $f(0,0) = 0, f(0,1) = f(1,0) = 1/2, f(1,1) = 1$. Then your sum can be expressed as $(X_1 + X_n) / 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(Y_k)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thahk you very much. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome. I gave it as a comment because I had no idea whether it would be helpful or completely off-track.

Comment: Why not use the simpler $f(0,0)=f(0,1)=0$ and $f(1,0)=f(1,1)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question an be marked as answered:

As Paul Sinclair wrote in a comment, there are $4$ possible values of $Y_n$; define $f(0,0)=0$, $f(0,1)=f(1,0)=1/2$, $f(1,1)=1$; then your sum can be expressed as $(X_1 + X_n) / 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(Y_k)$.